# Using Session data to link post to user ID

Tags: php, mysql

After solving my recent problem of joining tables, I now have 2 tables, one called `users` and the other called `posts`. The users table of course has a `user_name` and `user_id` and the posts also have a field named `user_id`, thus providing me with a way to link them with a mysql JOIN... the issue is I do not know how to use Session data to record the user's ID as they submit the blog post form. If I can just get that, I can then link the two tables. Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Blog Form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<p>
    <input type="hidden" name="user" id="user" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']['username'] ?>" readonly />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="title">Title: </label>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" />
</p>
<p>
    <textarea name="body" rows="20" cols="60"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Post" />
</p>
</form>
```

I was thinking I can potentially use `$_SESSION['user']['id']` to bind it to the table somehow but can't wrap my mind around it.

Comment: uh, `insert posts (user_id, post_text) values ($_SESSION['userid'], '$post_text')`?

Comment: Execute that as the form submits?

Comment: I got it all figured out. I would just execute what you just said as my script ran an `add_post($title, $body)` function that I did not include above. Beautiful thanks guys (Marc B you've helped me a lot today). Why is coding so much fun.

Comment: Can you phrase this as an answer so I can upvote it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working:

`insert posts (user_id, post_text) values ($_SESSION['userid'], '$post_text')`

For those who still need an answer to the question! Good luck.